# How to customize Java GraphQL error response

Tags: java, error-handling, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to modify graphql error response. I would like to remove null attributes from response. Is it possible?

[Current response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih6ld.png)

I created my GraphQL exception like ExceptionWhileDataFetching and my own definition for filter clients' errors. It works nice but ugly empty attributes are here and I want to remove them.

For example by [GraphQL docs](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-java/7-error-handling/) attribute extensions should be optional and on second example screen is only message attribute. It is what I want achieve but I cant find out how..

I found GraphqlErrorHelper#toSpecification.. I thought it is enough to override it and GraphQL library will proccess error attributes without other actions, but it didn't..

UPDATE:

I start thinking if I'm trying to do legit thing.. I found out that my `ClientException` will go correctly to `getJacksonMapper().writeValueAsString` in `GraphQLObjectMapper#serializeResultAsJson` and here is response somehow changed.. This part is bit magic for me.. :(

[Debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPBC4.png)

Comment: Is it not working to override filterGraphQLErrors method and remove null value attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this. In `filterGraphQLErrors` I should only choose which error I want to see, not change their structure, right? 
I tryied to debug it, but when for example `MyException#getPath` is called, it is from huge series of invokes and i cant find out where exactly is response created and how is these damn `nulls` assigned to reponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally find out solution..

`JacksonSerialer` use annotations for appending extra data.

So if I use `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` in my `GraphQLError` class all works as I want..

Finally [result I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyh72.png)